# Set an array session variable in Yii

Tags: php, session, yii

I need to to sth like this:

```
$_SESSION['key']['subkey1'] = 'value1';
$_SESSION['key']['subkey2'] = 'value2';
```

If I do it the Yii way, I get an error:
`Indirect modification of overloaded element of CHttpSession has no effect`

```
Yii::app()->session['key']['subkey1'] = 'value1';
Yii::app()->session['key']['subkey2'] = 'value2';
```

I could probably do sth like this:

`Yii::app()->session['key'] = array('subkey1' => 'value1', 'subkey2' => 'value2')`

This would be OK, but the problem still is that I cannot modify the values

```
Yii::app()->session['key']['subkey2'] = 'value3';
```

Any ideas? Is there actually any difference in using $_SESSION and Yii::app()->session ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
$temp = Yii::app()->session;
$temp['key']['subkey1'] = 'value1';
$temp['key']['subkey2'] = 'value2';
Yii::app()->session = $temp;
```

It's a workaround for the overloading error.

You can't directly modify an overloaded element because they don't really exist like properties do. You can read more about it here:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php

And you can read more about the differences between $_SESSION and Yii::app()->session here:
http://www.larryullman.com/2011/05/03/using-sessions-with-the-yii-framework/

Comment: so actually there is NO really other way. I have read the blog you linked before, it is a nice one, but from my understanding there is really no difference in using the normal way and the Yii way. Why should I do what you suggest, when I can directly assign to $_SESSION... but thanks for the answer

Comment: Personal preference, i guess. I like to use Yii's session stuff for consistency's sake. But i don't think there is any disadvantage to modifying the superglobal either, unless Yii decides to update in the future and change how things are stored.